# JavaScript Class toggle

Tags: javascript, css

I've working through a live search bar tutorial and have been trying to hide the characters list from view until a key is hit in the search bar. I've been told to use "element.class.toggle" but haven't been able to get it to work. Essentially I want  `display: none`   on the `charactersList`   class when the page initially loads, but then toggle to `display: grid` when any key is pressed inside the searchbar.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Project: https://codepen.io/jamesqquick/pen/XWJxBQv

```
const charactersList = document.getElementById('charactersList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
let hpCharacters = [];

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filteredCharacters = hpCharacters.filter((character) => {
        return (
            character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
            character.house.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        );
    });
    displayCharacters(filteredCharacters);
});

const loadCharacters = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters');
        hpCharacters = await res.json();
        displayCharacters(hpCharacters);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
    const htmlString = characters
        .map((character) => {
            return `
            <li class="character">
                <h2>${character.name}</h2>
                <p>House: ${character.house}</p>
                <img src="${character.image}"></img>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadCharacters();
```

Comment: Hey @Marcel, please edit your question and precise your issue exaclty.

Comment: I've edited it and hopefully it's a little clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to your JS

```
    function myFunction() {
      var charactersList = document.getElementById("charactersList");
      charactersList.style.display = "grid";

//also check if searchBar is empty and set display back to none
      var searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
      if (searchBar === ""){
        charactersList.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

And add this to your search bar:

```
onkeyup="myFunction()"
```

You can read here about [HTML DOM KeyboardEvents](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_keyboardevent.asp);

And of course set your `#charactersList` to  `display: none;`

```js
const charactersList = document.getElementById('charactersList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
let hpCharacters = [];

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filteredCharacters = hpCharacters.filter((character) => {
        return (
            character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
            character.house.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        );
    });
    displayCharacters(filteredCharacters);
});

const loadCharacters = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters');
        hpCharacters = await res.json();
        displayCharacters(hpCharacters);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
    const htmlString = characters
        .map((character) => {
            return `
            <li class="character">
                <h2>${character.name}</h2>
                <p>House: ${character.house}</p>
                <img src="${character.image}"></img>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadCharacters();

    function myFunction() {
      var charactersList = document.getElementById("charactersList");
      charactersList.style.display = "grid";

//also check if searchBar is empty and set display back to none
      var searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
      if (searchBar === ""){
        charactersList.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #111d4a;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.container {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
}

#charactersList {
    padding-inline-start: 0;
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.character {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        'name image'
        'house image';
    text-align: left;
}

.character > h2 {
    grid-area: name;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.character > p {
    grid-area: house;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -18px;
}

.character > img {
    max-height: 100px;
    grid-area: image;
}

#searchBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#searchWrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#searchWrapper::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>&#x2728;Harry Potter Characters &#x2728;</h1>
            <div id="searchWrapper">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="searchBar"
                    id="searchBar"
                    placeholder="search for a character"
                       onkeyup="myFunction()"
                />
            </div>
            <ul id="charactersList"></ul>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did exactly that and it still doesn't want to work. I've tried several similar ways that should work but don't so feel like I must be missing something. Maybe the dynamic loading of the list is causing problems?

Comment: @MarcelPenney This exact code works in your codepen, i tested it first.

Comment: #characterList display is none, I added the function right beneath the variables, and added the onkeyup to the top of the searchbar function. Here's my code now: https://codepen.io/MarcelPenn/pen/VweWKQN

Comment: @MarcelPenney in my solution you need to add onkeyup="myFunction()" to your HTML input element searchBar. I said in my answer And add this to your search bar: Then it works on you new codepen

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Sorry I know you're basically spelling it out for me but 've been stuck on this for 3 days. Would I use document.getElementByID()?

Comment: @MarcelPenney No litreray add that little code in your HTML input like this:

Comment: @MarcelPenney <input
                    type="text"
                    name="searchBar"
                    id="searchBar"
                    placeholder="search for a character" onkeyup="myFunction()"
                />

Comment: @MarcelPenney Also take note I changed the function so it checks if search bar is empty, to set results back to none.

Comment: Ok I didn't realize i could write that directly in the html, thanks. Right so you wrote an if statement inside the searchBar function? I'll try it.

Comment: @MarcelPenney There are multiple ways how to add JS events, I just chose this one by chance now. Here I made a snippet in answer for you to see it working.

Comment: @MarcelPenney You have some examples here how to call a function on some events: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate it you've been a big help